# SharePoint Link Click Error

Tags: sharepoint

Whenever I click on a link in SharePoint, ex: Excel document, SSRS Report, etc.; I always get an error that the page cannot be found. This is because "_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" is the default behaviour on click.
If I wight click and choose Open in New Tab, then it works fine.

How can I remove "_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" from being the default behaviour on click in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a setting in Central Admin which adds headers to the browser to download certain types of files.

You can change this setting by going to Central Admin >> Manage Web Applications >> select your Web Application >> General Settings and under "Browser File Handling" change it from "Strict" to "Permissive" or vice versa.

The automatic downloading forced by "strict" is a security feature, but can create a terrible user experience.  Once it's set to "permissive" you can control the behavior for each MIME type individually, but the defaults should be fine.

If you need to change the settings for a MIME type here's link to do so using powershell:  http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1187

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but in my case it is permissive.